# Issue with producer in Artemis

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

Hello I am trying to produce messages to my queue that is uploaded in my server and I am using spring-boot-starter-artemis. I don't have any problem with my consumer when I send messages from the server side my application can consume it. But when trying to produce I get this exception : **javax.jms.JMSException: There is no queue with name myqueueName**

```
@Component
public class ArtemisProducer {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Value("${jms.queue.destination}")
    String destinationQueue;
    
    public void send(String msg){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }
}
```

Config file :

```
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.host=host
spring.artemis.port=port
spring.artemis.user=username
spring.artemis.password=password
jms.queue.destination=myqueue
```

Exception :

```
  "exception": "org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException",
  "message": "Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is javax.jms.JMSException: There is no queue with name myqueue",
```

Comment: Can you share your broker.xml?

Comment: i didn't configure the broker and it was build by the infra team. the user i have has limited access. thank you I tried the code on new project and it worked fine with latest version of spring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked by changing the spring version to latest. I don't know how but that was the problem

Comment: what version was you using before?

Comment: org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:2.1.0 to org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis spring boot was : 2.2 and change it to latest

Answer (score 1):

By default both addresses and queues are created automatically. It sounds like this functionality has been disabled on your broker. You should either enable automatic address & queue creation using the following address-settings:

```xml
<auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
<auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
```

Or create the address and queue manually, e.g.:

```xml
<addresses>
   <address name="myqueue">
      <anycast>
         <queue name="myqueue"/>
      </anycast>
   </address>
</addresses>
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I cannot edit any thing in the broker since  it was deployed for me in a server. however It worked by changing the spring version which is weird :) but im glad it finally worked.

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ Artemis was the broker and what version of `spring-boot-starter-artemis` were you using before and after?

Comment: org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:2.1.0 to org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis spring boot was : 2.2 and change it to latest

Comment: do you by chance know if JmsListener handle request in transactional way in case of faulier return message to queue ? I searched about it and didn't get it if artemis with jms have some configuration you can add. I tried to add JmsListenerContainerFactory to my config class but it didn't work